# Continuous integration in business intelligence

Tags: continuous-integration, business-intelligence

I'm looking into getting BI teams to use continuous integration (CI). Searching online I found some articles that take you through the process of setting up CI for your BI database.

The thing all that those articles seem to forget, is that with BI continuous integration you would like (at least we like to) to run all tests and use a production-like database to find unforseen scenarios. Our BI databases can size up to terabytes, so the tests take a while.

Are there solutions that deal with this problem (maybe a tool that creates a smaller test db without losing valuable testdata)?

Answer (score 2):

CI needs quick tests. That is not your case. I will use **CI Builds** and **Nightly Builds**

**CI Build**

As soon as someone checks in, you launch the build, deploy to your CI/DEV environment and execute smoke tests and, if you want, a subset of your tests. The CI/DEV environment DB will contain only test data. Anyways, your tests should take small amount of time... the lesser the best.

So after each check in you get sure that at least your project **still** works.

**Nightly Build**

Layer I would setup manually a **nightly build** so you have lot of time to perform the tests. 
You should have a specific environment for tests. Your build should do:

1. Delete old DB.
2. Get the a backup of production database from a repository (ideally this repository should be updated very often)
3. You CI build restores backup in your Test environment
4. You deploy the latest successful build (the one deployed to you CI/DEV environment)
5. Run the tests during all night.

This way you will have 12-14 hours to run your build and everyday, **when you arrive at work you will have feedback on the test results for the previous day**.

If your tests take more than 12-14 hours (terrabytes?) then you should review them as probably something is wrong (or you work with google db)

Comment: Well we're working with BI databases, so they tend to get real big and are used in every unit test. I edited my question with another more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

In reviewing Integration Services from Microsoft I looks like it has an flexible solution. Also Chef at https://www.getchef.com/ has a great open Source solution.

Both of these support

1. Building the solution
2. Build the environment.
3. Running Unit and UI tests.
4. Migrating the solution to the correct environment.
5. messaging group on status of the changes.